# Database in IOS Sqlite3 and db

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

I am learning some concepts in the iOS database... I come to know that  sqlite3 (open source ) is used for databases,
but I was going through some of the github code...

and come across these two lines:

```
NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banklist" 
        ofType:@"sqlite3"]
```

and

```
 NSString *databaseFilename =@"abc.db"
```

1. can you please tell me where we will use the `sqlite3` and where `db`?
2. can you also provide me some good links to learn the database for the iOS (from the sample project when I open the `db` file in the textedit I can't understand it)?
3. how can I open the `db` file and `sqlite` file?
4. is there any free tool is available in iOS to read these database files?

Comment: The name of the file can be anything you want.  It could be "Airplane.java" if that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked:

> can you please tell me where we will use the `sqlite3` and where `db`

You can use either extension. It doesn't matter. Both `sqlite` (without the 3) and `db` are commonly used.

> can you also provide me some good links to learn the database for the iOS

Google "ios sqlite tutorial"

I generally like Ray Wenderlich tutorials and his SQLite tutorial is here: [SQLite 101 for iPhone Developers: Making Our App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app). My only criticism of that tutorial is that I don't like the fact that he's open a database from the bundle. You should always copy database from bundle to Documents folder first, before opening the database in the Documents folder.

> how can i open the db file and sqlite file

You open databases (i.e., a file, conventionally with either `db` or `sqlite` extension) the same way. It's the same sort of file, just a different extension. The general process is either:

- Create database on your mac and include it in the project and the resulting bundle. Then, programmatically you check to see if database already exists in the Documents folder and, if not, copy from the bundle to Documents folder (if you do this, you might want to use [`sqlite3_open_v2`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) with the `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` option, but not the `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` option, so the database won't be created if it's not found); or
- Create database programmatically by (a) check to see if it exists in Documents and if not, create database (with either [`sqlite3_open_v2`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) with the `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` options or just [`sqlite3_open`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) (which uses those two options by default)) and then execute the SQL `CREATE` statements; or (b) if it already exists in the Documents folder, just use it.

If you go through the various tutorials you find, they'll walk you through or approach or the other. Both techniques are valid.

> is there any free tool is available in iOS to read these database files

I don't think there are iOS tools (as apps keep their files (and a database is just a type of file) in their respective sandboxes and thus one app can't open a database in another app's Documents folder). But there are lots of Mac tools that you use during development.

- The `sqlite3` program available in the `Terminal` command line interface.
- I use [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/), an ok, fairly basic tool
- I think a lot of people use a FireFox [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) tool

---

You didn't ask, but if you're starting SQLite development, using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) can *greatly* simplify your Objective-C code. And I'd be remiss if I didn't note the [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is the preferred database technology for iOS development. There can be compelling reasons to use SQLite (via FMDB, for example), but Apple engineered the rich Core Data framework that has some advantages for iOS-only apps. It's a little more complicated, but has some advantages.

Comment: hey thanks for the info but one doubt how to install FireFox SQLite Manager tool ...bcz it is a .xpi file ??

Comment: @user2353519 you install it on your Mac where you're doing your development (and, of course, only if you use Firefox). You don't install SQLite tools on the device, but rather on your development machine.

Comment: yes man I am trying to install in mac but i downloaded but its a .xpi format file ..which is not opening to install .. that i am asking to install

Comment: @user2353519 Yes. It is a FireFox add on.

Comment: Hi @Rob , why "should always copy database from bundle to Documents folder first"? Is this true even if I use a database just to read data and never modify it?

Answer (score 2):

Let! me try to answer your all questions one by one

1.The  below line

```
NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banklist" 
        ofType:@"sqlite3"]
```

is saying we will create **banklist.sqlite3** file for storing our database.

---

2.we use the sqlite database, whenever we need to store application's info locally, it can be your choice.

---

3.**For learning sqlite I have created simple step by step Tutorial with sample code**

> [**SQLIte in iPhone Tutorial**](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/sqlite-in-iphone-tutorial_8077.html)

I would suggest you please! read and do it by yourself complete, you will get all the answers of your questions.

---

4.for reading or editing I use one open source tool name "**sqlite browser**"
you can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

---

5.you can find your apps db file and open with the tool I mentioned.
here is the db file path you can find in your system .

**Note** : This is just a reference for your app path will be different but in the same way

*/Users/RDCMac/Library/Application Support/iPhone
 Simulator/6.1/Applications/0975F545-E4D2-40E8-97C6-0EA7F8995315/Documents/contacts.db*

### -----------------

Please! let me know if you need any help in this, glad to help!!

Comment: @user2353519 is that helpful for you :) , if you need I can explain you each and every step in that. let me know if you get any trouble

Comment: ya still I have trouble with sqlite and db..  for both syntax will be different ..

Comment: @user2353519  we use the SQL query for sqlite database what we use for MySQL etc., could you clear when you say db?

Comment: like in some cases i have seen we are using extension .db and some cases we are using .sqlite3 ..so where to use db and when

Answer (score 1):

A.1. You can name the file whatever you like. but keep the extension to `.sqlite3` is more reasonable.
According to your above example, two things can happen. In the first case, For an iPhone app a database file can be already added in the project bundle and you use the database in your app. This database is read only.

Or, in 2nd case, you can store and modify data in your app. In that case you name an sqlite file, and later on database operation you manipulate that file. Usually this database file should be stored in the device's documents folder. 
Also, coredata can use a sqlite file store and do operation on the database file.

A useful technique to have a modifiable database in the bundle is to copy the database to document folder on the first run. remember that anything in the bundle is not modifiable.

A.3. You can use a firefox plugin to open, create and modify sqlite files. https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

A.4. Not clear. Do you want something like the third question for iOS.

Comment: hey thanks for the info but one doubt how to install FireFox SQLite Manager tool ...bcz it is a .xpi file ??

Comment: go firefox add ons, then search for sqlite manager. install from there. firefox will install automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1) sqlite3 is the extension used for sqlite database files. And db is generally used for database files. You can use either use sqlite3 or db. There is no issue with this.

Reference: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847067/what-is-difference-between-sqlite-and-db-file)

2) Tutorials:

- [iOS SQLite Database Application](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/Tutorial-on-Creating-an-IOS-5-SQLite-Database-Application-IOS-5-SQLite)
- [SQLite based iOS 6 Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_6_iPhone_Application)
- [Sqlite for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app)

3) For opening the db or sqlite file you can use any sqlite tools.

4) [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) is a free addon for firefox. Which is a handy tool for creating sqlite database

Comment: hey thanks for the info but one doubt how to install FireFox SQLite Manager tool ...bcz it is a .xpi file ??

Comment: @user2353519: open the Tools->Add ons option from firefox. Click on the settings button of that page Select Install Add-on from file option. Choose the xpi file

Comment: there is no add on option in my tools ...do i need to install firefox browser

Comment: @user2353519: Yes. You need to install firefox first. And open it, then you'll see a tools menu for firefox. After that do like above