# convert sqlite database to .db file

Tags: database, sqlite

I was working on SQLite database and need to convert it to a .db extension instead of having data.sqlite. My client needs the data in data.db extension. So is there any way to convert the data.sqlite file into data.db file?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847067/what-is-difference-between-sqlite-and-db-file

Answer (score 7):

The name of your file is completely irrelevant to the data inside of it. Assuming the data structure is properly setup, simply renaming the file will suffice.

Note: If you're running windows, you will need to enable file extension visibility.

Comment: so what you are saying is if I rename the database to some meaningful name and than rename the database file with db extension it I will get convereted database?

Comment: No. Jacob is saying that you've only asked for a particular name. Renaming the file will result in an SQLite database with a different name. If you really want it converted to another format you should ask about _that_ instead of asking about the name.

Comment: It was so silly of me, I just rename the database from data.sqlite to data.db and it is working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment I really appreciate it. I was only trying to change the extension of the file.